# wicked pdf page background image with pdf_from_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I need to add a background image to the generated PDF using pdf_from_string method.

This is my code

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html,
           header: {
                content: render_to_string('pdf/pdf_header.html.erb', layout: 'pdf_layout.html.erb')
           },
           footer: {
                content: render_to_string('pdf/pdf_footer.html.erb', layout: 'pdf_layout.html.erb')
           },
           background: true,
           save_to_file: Rails.root.join("pdfs","#{pdf_name}.pdf"),
           save_only: true
        )
```

the header and footer is working fine, but I did not find a way to add the background image option, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using render_to_string method and passing the HTML content as locals to the template like the following:

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string('pdf/pdf_full_page.html.erb', layout:'pdf_layout.html.erb', locals: { content: html}),
           header: {
                content: render_to_string('pdf/pdf_header.html.erb', layout: 'pdf_layout.html.erb')
           },
           footer: {
                content: render_to_string('pdf/pdf_footer.html.erb', layout: 'pdf_layout.html.erb')
           },
           layout: 'pdf_layout.html.erb',
           debug: true,
           background: true,
           no_background: false,
           save_to_file: Rails.root.join("pdfs","#{pdf_name}.pdf"),
           save_only: true
        )
```

pdf_full_page.html.erb View code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PDF Full page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%= content.html_safe %>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps someone else